# Why in Angular 2, ErrorHandler module doesn't exist?

Tags: angular

When I import the "ErrorHandler" module like this:

```js
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
```

Visual studio indicates "Module .../@angular/core/index has no exported member 'ErrorHandler'"

Why ? It isn't installed ? how to install it ?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install @angular/core
```

try reinstall core module

or update package.json file and run

```
npm install
```

Comment: thx but it doesn't work... I tried to update package.json "2.0.0-rc.5" -> "^2.3.1" and again "npm install @angular/core" but it doesn't work either

Comment: try making it  "@angular/core": "~2.1.2"

Comment: @amorel It happens with the libraries.... u need the version of code in sync with the libraries....